# Undefined is not an Object (evaluating 'props.contacts.reduce') - React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm learning React Native and trying to run this app which I learnt, but for me, an error is thrown like this.[Undefined is not an Object (evaluating 'props.contacts.reduce')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npJNR.jpg)

Edit : I'm adding all other code used in this app. I'm unable to find the error. Please help. I'm just learning how this works and I'm not the one who created this.This is the progam that the error is pointing to :

SectionListContacts.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {SectionList, Text} from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import Row from './Row'

const renderSectionHeader = ({section}) => <Text>{section.title}</Text>

const SectionListContacts = props => {
  const contactsByLetter = props.contacts.reduce((obj, contact) => {
    const firstLetter = contact.name[0].toUpperCase()
    return {
      ...obj,
      [firstLetter]: [...(obj[firstLetter] || []), contact],
    }
  }, {})

  const sections = Object.keys(contactsByLetter)
    .sort()
    .map(letter => ({
      data: contactsByLetter[letter],
      title: letter,
    }))

  return (
    <SectionList
      keyExtractor={item => item.phone}
      sections={sections}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Row {...item} onSelectContact={props.onSelectContact} />}
      renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
    />
  )
}

SectionListContacts.propTypes = {
  contacts: PropTypes.array,
}

export default SectionListContacts
```

App.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'

import AddContactScreen from './screens/AddContactScreen'
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen'
import ContactListScreen from './screens/ContactListScreen'
import ContactDetailsScreen from './screens/ContactDetailsScreen'
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen'
import {fetchUsers} from './api'
import contacts from './contacts'
import store from './redux/store'

const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    ContactList: ContactListScreen,
    ContactDetails: ContactDetailsScreen,
    AddContact: AddContactScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'ContactList',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTintColor: '#a41034',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
    },
  }
)

MainStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (
    <Ionicons name={`ios-contacts${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`} size={25} color={tintColor} />
  ),
}

const MainTabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Contacts: MainStack,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#a41034',
    },
  }
)

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Main: MainTabs,
})

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    contacts,
  }

  /*
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers()
  }

  getUsers = async () => {
    const results = await fetchUsers()
    this.setState({contacts: results})
  }
  */

  addContact = newContact => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      contacts: [...prevState.contacts, newContact],
    }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainTabs />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

api.js

```js
const processContact = contact => ({
  name: `${contact.name.first} ${contact.name.last}`,
  phone: contact.phone,
})

export const fetchUsers = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50&nat=us')
  const {results} = await response.json()
  return results.map(processContact)
}

export const login = async (username, password) => {
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({username, password}),
  })

  if (response.ok) {
    return true
  }

  const errMessage = await response.text()
  throw new Error(errMessage)
}
```

AddContactForm.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Button, KeyboardAvoidingView, StyleSheet, TextInput, View} from 'react-native'

export default class AddContactForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: '',
    phone: '',
    isFormValid: false,
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.name !== prevState.name || this.state.phone !== prevState.phone) {
      this.validateForm()
    }
  }

  getHandler = key => val => {
    this.setState({[key]: val})
  }

  handleNameChange = this.getHandler('name') // val => { this.setState({name: val}) }
  handlePhoneChange = this.getHandler('phone')

  /*
  handleNameChange = name => {
    this.setState({name})
  }
  */

  handlePhoneChange = phone => {
    if (+phone >= 0 && phone.length <= 10) {
      this.setState({phone})
    }
  }

  validateForm = () => {
    console.log(this.state)
    const names = this.state.name.split(' ')
    if (
      +this.state.phone >= 0 &&
      this.state.phone.length === 10 &&
      names.length >= 2 &&
      names[0] &&
      names[1]
    ) {
      this.setState({isFormValid: true})
    } else {
      this.setState({isFormValid: false})
    }
  }

  validateForm2 = () => {
    if (+this.state.phone >= 0 && this.state.phone.length === 10 && this.state.name.length >= 3) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.name}
          onChangeText={this.getHandler('name')}
          placeholder="Name"
        />
        <TextInput
          keyboardType="numeric"
          style={styles.input}
          value={this.state.phone}
          onChangeText={this.getHandler('phone')}
          placeholder="Phone"
        />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={this.handleSubmit} disabled={!this.state.isFormValid} />
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  input: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'black',
    minWidth: 100,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    borderRadius: 3,
  },
})
```

contacts.js

```js
const NUM_CONTACTS = 3

const firstNames = [
  'Emma',
  'Noah',
  'Olivia',
  'Liam',
  'Ava',
  'William',
  'Sophia',
  'Mason',
  'Isabella',
  'James',
  'Mia',
  'Benjamin',
  'Charlotte',
  'Jacob',
  'Abigail',
  'Michael',
  'Emily',
  'Elijah',
  'Harper',
  'Ethan',
  'Amelia',
  'Alexander',
  'Evelyn',
  'Oliver',
  'Elizabeth',
  'Daniel',
  'Sofia',
  'Lucas',
  'Madison',
  'Matthew',
  'Avery',
  'Aiden',
  'Ella',
  'Jackson',
  'Scarlett',
  'Logan',
  'Grace',
  'David',
  'Chloe',
  'Joseph',
  'Victoria',
  'Samuel',
  'Riley',
  'Henry',
  'Aria',
  'Owen',
  'Lily',
  'Sebastian',
  'Aubrey',
  'Gabriel',
  'Zoey',
  'Carter',
  'Penelope',
  'Jayden',
  'Lillian',
  'John',
  'Addison',
  'Luke',
  'Layla',
  'Anthony',
  'Natalie',
  'Isaac',
  'Camila',
  'Dylan',
  'Hannah',
  'Wyatt',
  'Brooklyn',
  'Andrew',
  'Zoe',
  'Joshua',
  'Nora',
  'Christopher',
  'Leah',
  'Grayson',
  'Savannah',
  'Jack',
  'Audrey',
  'Julian',
  'Claire',
  'Ryan',
  'Eleanor',
  'Jaxon',
  'Skylar',
  'Levi',
  'Ellie',
  'Nathan',
  'Samantha',
  'Caleb',
  'Stella',
  'Hunter',
  'Paisley',
  'Christian',
  'Violet',
  'Isaiah',
  'Mila',
  'Thomas',
  'Allison',
  'Aaron',
  'Alexa',
  'Lincoln',
]

const lastNames = [
  'Smith',
  'Jones',
  'Brown',
  'Johnson',
  'Williams',
  'Miller',
  'Taylor',
  'Wilson',
  'Davis',
  'White',
  'Clark',
  'Hall',
  'Thomas',
  'Thompson',
  'Moore',
  'Hill',
  'Walker',
  'Anderson',
  'Wright',
  'Martin',
  'Wood',
  'Allen',
  'Robinson',
  'Lewis',
  'Scott',
  'Young',
  'Jackson',
  'Adams',
  'Tryniski',
  'Green',
  'Evans',
  'King',
  'Baker',
  'John',
  'Harris',
  'Roberts',
  'Campbell',
  'James',
  'Stewart',
  'Lee',
  'County',
  'Turner',
  'Parker',
  'Cook',
  'Mc',
  'Edwards',
  'Morris',
  'Mitchell',
  'Bell',
  'Ward',
  'Watson',
  'Morgan',
  'Davies',
  'Cooper',
  'Phillips',
  'Rogers',
  'Gray',
  'Hughes',
  'Harrison',
  'Carter',
  'Murphy',
]

// generate a random number between min and max
const rand = (max, min = 0) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min

// generate a name
const generateName = () =>
  `${firstNames[rand(firstNames.length - 1)]} ${lastNames[rand(lastNames.length - 1)]}`

// generate a phone number
const generatePhoneNumber = () => `${rand(999, 100)}-${rand(999, 100)}-${rand(9999, 1000)}`

// create a person
const createContact = () => ({
  name: generateName(),
  phone: generatePhoneNumber(),
})

// compare two contacts for alphabetizing
export const compareNames = (contact1, contact2) => contact1.name > contact2.name

// add keys to based on index
const addKeys = (val, key) => ({key, ...val})

// create an array of length NUM_CONTACTS and add keys
export default Array.from({length: NUM_CONTACTS}, createContact).map(addKeys)
```

FlatListContacts.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {FlatList} from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import Row from './Row'

const renderItem = ({item}) => <Row {...item} />

const FlatListContacts = props => <FlatList renderItem={renderItem} data={props.contacts} />

FlatListContacts.propTypes = {
  contacts: PropTypes.array,
}

export default FlatListContacts
```

Row.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {padding: 20},
})

const Row = props => (
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.row} onPress={() => props.onSelectContact(props)}>
    <Text>{props.name}</Text>
    <Text>{props.phone}</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

Row.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  phone: PropTypes.string,
}

export default Row
```

ScrollViewContacts.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {ScrollView} from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import Row from './Row'

const ScrollViewContacts = props => (
  <ScrollView>{props.contacts.map(contact => <Row {...contact} />)}</ScrollView>
)

ScrollViewContacts.propTypes = {
  contacts: PropTypes.array,
}

export default ScrollViewContacts
```

(Directory : screens)

AddContactScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import AddContactForm from '../AddContactForm'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

import {addContact} from '../redux/actions'

class AddContactScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: 'New Contact',
  }

  handleSubmit = formState => {
    this.props.addContact({name: formState.name, phone: formState.phone})
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ContactList')
  }

  render() {
    return <AddContactForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
  }
}

export default connect(null, {addContact: addContact})(AddContactScreen)
```

ContactDetailsScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Button, Text, View} from 'react-native'

export default class ContactDetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerTitle: navigation.getParam('name'),
  })

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.navigation.getParam('phone')}</Text>
        <Button title="Go to random contact" onPress={this.goToRandomContact} />
      </View>
    )
  }

  goToRandomContact = () => {
    const {contacts} = this.props.screenProps
    const phone = this.props.navigation.getParam('phone')
    let randomContact
    while (!randomContact) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * contacts.length)
      if (contacts[randomIndex].phone !== phone) {
        randomContact = contacts[randomIndex]
      }
    }

    // this.props.navigation.navigate('ContactDetails', {
    //   ...randomContact,
    // });
    this.props.navigation.push('ContactDetails', {
      ...randomContact,
    })
  }
}
```

ContactListScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Button, View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

import SectionListContacts from '../SectionListContacts'

class ContactListScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    headerTitle: 'Contacts',
    headerRight: (
      <Button title="Add" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddContact')} color="#a41034" />
    ),
  })

  state = {
    showContacts: true,
  }

  toggleContacts = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({showContacts: !prevState.showContacts}))
  }

  handleSelectContact = contact => {
    this.props.navigation.push('ContactDetails', contact)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="toggle contacts" onPress={this.toggleContacts} />
        {this.state.showContacts && (
          <SectionListContacts
            contacts={this.props.contacts}
            onSelectContact={this.handleSelectContact}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  contacts: state.contacts,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ContactListScreen)
```

LoginScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Button, View, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput} from 'react-native'

import {login} from '../api'

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  }

  _login = async () => {
    try {
      const success = await login(this.state.username, this.state.password)
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')
    } catch (err) {
      const errMessage = err.message
      this.setState({err: errMessage})
    }
  }

  handleUsernameUpdate = username => {
    this.setState({username})
  }

  handlePasswordUpdate = password => {
    this.setState({password})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.err}</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="username"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChangeText={this.handleUsernameUpdate}
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          placeholder="password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChangeText={this.handlePasswordUpdate}
          secureTextEntry
        />
        <Button title="Press to Log In" onPress={this._login} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  error: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'red',
  },
})
```

SettingsScreen.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import {Button, View, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native'

import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'

export default class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => (
      <Ionicons name={`ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`} size={25} color={tintColor} />
    ),
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Settings coming soon.</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  text: {
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
})
```

(End of Directory)

(Directory : Redux)

Actions.js

```js
// action types
export const UPDATE_USER = 'UPDATE_USER'
export const UPDATE_CONTACT = 'UPDATE_CONTACT'

// action creators
export const updateUser = update => ({
  type: UPDATE_USER,
  payload: update,
})

export const addContact = newContact => ({
  type: UPDATE_CONTACT,
  payload: newContact,
})
```

store.js

```js
import {createStore} from 'redux'

import {addContact} from './actions'
import reducer from './reducer'

const store = createStore(reducer)

/*
store.dispatch(updateUser({foo: 'foo'}))
store.dispatch(updateUser({bar: 'bar'}))
store.dispatch(updateUser({foo: 'baz'}))
*/

store.dispatch(addContact({name: 'jordan h', phone: '1234567890'}))
store.dispatch(addContact({name: 'jordan h', phone: '1234567890'}))
store.dispatch(addContact({name: 'david m', phone: '5050505050'}))

console.log(store.getState())

export default store
```

reducer.js

```js
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

import {UPDATE_USER, UPDATE_CONTACT} from './actions'

const merge = (prev, next) => Object.assign({}, prev, next)

const contactReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  if (action.type === UPDATE_CONTACT) return [...state, action.payload]
  return state
}

const userReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_USER:
      return merge(state, action.payload)
    case UPDATE_CONTACT:
      return merge(state, {prevContact: action.payload})
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const reducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  contacts: contactReducer,
})

export default reducer
```

(End of Directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your component code is not the problem: The component who is rendering `SectionListContacts` is not passing property `contacts`. Thats why in runtime `props.contacts` is `undefined` and the app complains about you cannot use method reduce on it.

Comment: I've added the code that refers to SectionListContacts. Can you please suggest me a solution for the above error? Thanks.

Comment: Your `SectionListContacts` is just forwarding `contrats` from parent component. You need to go up in the component tree and find who is actually defining contracts.